# Sqoop logs in Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-emr, sqoop

I'm running a sqoop job in EMR:

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://server.com:1433;databaseName=db' --table myTable --target-dir s3://mylocation --username admin --password pass
```

It was working fine for previous runs. But now it's stuck for one of the tables and it does not throw any errors. After running the job, it is stuck at

```
17/03/07 13:28:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://xxx:20888/proxy/application_1488891031868_0010/
17/03/07 13:28:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1488891031868_0010
```

How can I see the detailed log and find out what went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Go to yarn container logs you will see everything

Answer (score 0):

Add `--verbose` in your sqoop command to check extended logs. It will print more information regarding classpath, split values, JDBC connection, MapReduce job, etc.